# CSS for Dropdown in safari

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

i am working in project that contains this kind of filters in which user can select values from dropdown, [the below image is from safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0B9y.png)

[the 2nd image is from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5CfQ.png)

Now how to make the dropdown in safari look as same that is in chrome

Comment: Remove the background color? Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: No it's not going to help.I haven't found any solution for this yet